# Plugin not enabled Error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, sharedpreferences, cordova-plugins

I am new to `ionic-framework`, trying to implement shared prefrences in ionic platform for which [cordovaPreferences](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/preferences/) is the plugin:

- I downloaded plugin with cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-preferences
- installed [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/)
- added ng-cordova.js in index.html before cordova.js
- added ngCordova' in my starter module
- injected $cordovaPreferences in controller

Then I am using:

```
$cordovaPreferences.store('key', 'myMagicValue')
  .success(function(value) {
     alert("Success: " + value);
   })
  .error(function(error) {
     alert("Error: " + error);
   })
```

But an alert is generated saying "Plugin not enabled":

[image: Screen shot of error]

Please Help.

Comment: You need to try to launch this in an emulator or a mobile device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run this app in Android or iOS.
Some plugins are not for the browser.

Following command is to add platform android

```
ionic platform add android
```

To build

```
ionic build android
```

To Emulate

```
ionic emulate android
```

If you are not satisfied with the emulation, after the `build` command, just go to `YourApp'sFolder\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk` and copy the `apk` file to your device and install

Check that the plugin is working successfully

Answer (score 3):

`ngCordova` preferences object is a wrapped version of [cordova app preferences plugin](https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences). I'm author of that plugin.

When you use preferences too early (before `deviceready` event), ngCordova will display alert window with "Plugin not enabled" message. [Here](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/blob/2b0cde28bf9b2e624f1903ca2188ac46c1c7fdae/src/plugins/preferences.js) is the code. Wait for `deviceready` event as Dirk D. suggests:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready (function () {
    // your code here
})
```

Another possibility why you see this alert is that you're trying to test your app in browser with `ionic serve` or `cordova serve` or `cordova run browser`, but browser platform is not available till plugin version 0.7.7 which I released today.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your call into :

$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

...

});